# Update the tabview when select the row in datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

In the below code i can update the tabview when i select the row in datatable.but here is one small problem is the editor in one of my tab is disable when select a row and the downlod is not working in first time if u click second time it will work correctly

```
<p:dataTable id="dataCall" var="call" value="#{calllist.mediumCallsModel}"
  selection="#{calllist.selectedCall}" scrollRows="20" scrollHeight="350" 
  scrollWidth="150" liveScroll="true" selectionMode="single" paginator="true" rows="5"
  widgetVar="callsTable" paginatorPosition="bottom" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,20,50">
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{calllist.onRowSelect}" update=":MyListForm:showlist: :MyListForm:growl  " />  

    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" listener="#{calllist.onRowUnselect}" update=":MyListForm:growl"/>

    <p:column headerText="Call ID">  
        <h:outputText value="#{call.callId}"/>  
    </p:column>  
    <p:column headerText="Created By">  
        <h:outputText value="#{call.createdBy}" />  
    </p:column>  
    <p:column headerText="Location">  
        <h:outputText value="#{call.location}" />  
    </p:column> 
    <p:column headerText="Status">  
        <h:outputText value="#{call.status}" />  
    </p:column> 
    <p:column headerText="Product">  
        <h:outputText value="#{call.product}" />  
    </p:column>  
    <p:column headerText="Module">  
        <h:outputText value="#{call.module}" />  
    </p:column>  
    <p:column headerText="Group Assigned">  
        <h:outputText value="#{call.groupAssigned}" />  
    </p:column>  
    <p:column headerText="Assigned to">  
        <h:outputText value="#{call.assignedTo}" />  
    </p:column> 
    <p:column headerText="Call creation">  
        <h:outputText value="#{call.callCreation}" />  
    </p:column>  
</p:dataTable>  

                <h:panelGrid >
                    <p:tabView id="showlist" cache="true" style="font-size: 15px; height: 260px;width: 995px">  
                        <p:tab id="tab1"  title="Call Details"> 
                            <p:fieldset id="calldetails" style="background-color: lightgray; font-weight: bold;color: black;">
                                <table border="0" width="900px" align="left" style="font-size: 12px">
                               <tr>
                                        <td width="100px"><h:outputText value="Status:"/></td>
                                        <td width="80px"><p:selectOneMenu id="status" value="#{calllist.selectedCall.statusId}"  style="width:114px; font-size: 12px">  
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Status" itemValue="-1" /> 
                                                <f:selectItems  value="#{calllist.dyStatusList}" />

                                            </p:selectOneMenu> </td> 

                                    </tr>
                                </table>  
                            </p:fieldset>
                        </p:tab> 

                        <p:tab title="Work log/Comments"> 

                            <table id="comment_table" width="900px" height="200px" border="0" style="font-size: 12px;">
                                <tr valign="top">
                                    <td>
                                        <div id="oldcomment" style="width:450px; height: 90px; background-color:lightgray;font-weight: bold;color: black;overflow: scroll;">
                                            <ui:repeat value="#{calllist.oldComments}" var="item">
                                                <table>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><h:outputText value="User ID"/></td>
                                                        <td><h:outputText value="#{item.modifiedUserID}"/></td>
                                                    </tr>

                                                </table>
                                                <hr/>   
                                            </ui:repeat>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="comment" style="width:450px; height: 90px; background-color:lightgray; font-weight: bold;color: black;" >

                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <p:editor id="editor"  width="400" height="190" onchange="append_comment();" value="#{calllist.comments}"/> 

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                        </p:tab>  

                        <p:tab title="Attachments">
                            <h:form id="download_form">
                                <table id="download_list">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <p:fileUpload id="upload" fileUploadListener="#{calllist.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" sizeLimit="100000" multiple="true" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|xls)$/" />
                                        </td> 
                                        <td>
                                            <p:selectOneListbox id="scroll" value="#{calllist.fileName}"  style="width: 250px;">
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue="-1"/>
                                                <f:selectItems value="#{calllist.attachment}"/>
                                            </p:selectOneListbox>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td align="center">

                                            <p:commandButton id="downloadLink" value="Download" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s"> 
                                                <p:fileDownload value="#{calllist.file}"/>    
                                            </p:commandButton> 

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </h:form>
                        </p:tab>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [datable not update the tabview but some contents in tabview is disable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569800/datable-not-update-the-tabview-but-some-contents-in-tabview-is-disable)

Comment: Please do not post same question over and over. Instead, edit and improve the original question. Or, if you can't seem to find the question back in the listing, click at link behind your username which appears in gray top bar (when logged in). It leads you to your user profile wherein you can find all your posts.